# How are "line integrals independent of any notion of any metric notions in space"?

Tags: electromagnetism, differential-geometry

So in the Frankel's geometry of physics:

> There are times when one needs to compute the arc length of a curve,
> but, usually, it is completely irrelevant to either the computation or
> the concept of a line integral! Line (and, as we shall see, surface)
> integrals are independent of any metric notions in space.
> This is one case where the usual elementary treatment given in many
> calculus texts is harmful and misleading and should have been discarded long ago

-(chapter $3$ - Integration of Differential Forms).

He then proceeds to give some examples within the context of electromagnetism. But computationally these examples seem to be the same(?) I feel he has made a profound statement and I'm missing the point. Can someone elaborate? (Or drive the point home)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably Frankel is essentially making the following point:

1. Consider an electromagnetic potential 1-form $A=A_{\mu}\mathrm{d}x^{\mu}$ on a [pseudo-Riemannian manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Riemannian_manifold) $(M,g)$. Then the line-integral $\int_{\gamma}A$ does not depend on the metric $g$.
2. Importantly, [topological field theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_quantum_field_theory) (TFT), such as [Chern-Simons (CS) theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chern%E2%80%93Simons_theory), are theories where the correlations functions don't depend on the metric $g$.